# Calling a Javascript Function as a Primitive Datatype(Number in particular)

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying out some new implementations for a project in express and i have this issue:

code snippet:

```js
let add_1 = () =>{
  console.log(2)
}

let a = add_1();

let add_2 = () => {
  console.log(5)
}

let z = add_2();

console.log(a +z);
```

upon running this code snippet i get a NaN

is there a way i can return the actual addition of these function calls (which in this case is 2+5=7) ?

Answer (score 2):

you should use return statement instead of console.log like below

```js
let add_1 = () =>{
  return 2;
}

let a = add_1();

let add_2 = () => {
  return 5;
}

let z = add_2();

console.log(a +z);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome @E-WAVE

Answer (score 2):

Your functions print to console but they do not return a value, so you cannot add them as numbers.

You can have each function do this `return 5;` or `return 2;` after the `console.log(..)` statement.

You can also user variables (instead of hard-coded values) or pass in parameters to the functions.

**See below:**

```js
let add_1 = () => {
  const val = 2;
  console.log(val);
  return val;
}

let a = add_1();

let add_2 = (val) => {
  console.log(val);
  return val;

}

let z = add_2(5);

console.log(a + z);
console.log(a + a);
console.log(z + z);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this !